# C# how to use e.suppresskeypress to restrict \ * ? " and other entries

Tags: c#

I can use e.suppresskeypress to restrict certain key presses in a textbox but cannot figure out how to use it to suppress entries like \ * ? or ". I can use the suppress when e.KeyCode == key.something, but there is no key.(special characters). I can suppress some entries such as letters or numbers but not these special characters. What can I do to suppress these special characters?

Comment: Did you check whether `Keys.OemBackslash` `Keys.OemQuotes` and [ `Keys.Multiply` or (`Keys.D8` and `Modifiers.Equals(Keys.Shift)`) etc. work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, due to the fact that you are actually performing a double keypress (I assume you press Shift in order to get a question mark as I have to do).

I am not entirely sure if this answer will help you, but you could try to catch the modifier key (which is the Shift key for instance) combined with the KeyValue (ie. ASCII value of that particular key that you want to exclude).

Just an example, to try within your KeyDown eventhandler:

```
int questionMark = 191; //This might actually not be the correct key
int star = 56;
int quoteKey = 222;

if (e.Modifiers.Equals(Keys.Shift))
{
  if (e.KeyValue.Equals(questionMark) ||
      e.KeyValue.Equals(star) ||
      e.KeyValue.Equals(quoteKey))
  {
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;                    
  }
}
```

I can imagine that the ASCII values might differ, depending on which keyboard layout you use. But it is worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter by KeyValue or KeyCode, as you prefer. Here are an example capturing with both methods.

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyValue == '\\') {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        } else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Multiply) {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

With KeyValue, you must filter by the ascii code of the character.

With KeyCode, you must compare against a value in the [Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) enum.

Comment: By ascii code do you mean he decimal version of it or just the special character in quotes like you put down? Also do all keys have an enum?

Comment: Ascii code is an integer value. Ie, ascii code of A = 65. In c#, you can compare char with integer (There is an implicit cast)

Comment: So this works if I try it with letters or numbers, and even backspace but won't work with special characters.... Any ideas?

Comment: Using some debugging I found out KeyValue was giving me another value besides what the ascii code should be thats why it wasn't working. Also this way blocks the whole key even if its shifted.